# Was Kylo Ren's hand cut off?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, kylo-ren

At the end of The Force Awakens, Kylo Ren falls into the snow and gets slashed at by Rey several times. A slash mark on his face is clearly visible.

Rey also slashes at one of Kylo's hands as he falls into the snow. Was his hand cut off at that point in time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no indication that she chopped his hand off.

> *He was up again in an instant, but not in time to fully deflect a
> following blow from Rey’s weapon. He succeeded in blocking it, but he
> still took the full force of the strike against the haft of his own
> lightsaber. The weapon went flying into the snow. Unarmed, he raised a
> hand and utilized the Force to fend off one slashing blow after
> another, until finally her fury penetrated his remaining defenses.
> Taking a glancing blow to the head and chest, he went down, a
> prominent burn slashed across his face. Weakened, he reached out
> toward his lightsaber, trying to draw it to him.*
>
> [Star Wars: The Force Awakens - Official Novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Force_Awakens_(novel))

and

> *Staggering back to his feet, his parry could not match the strength of
> her swing. It cast his lightsaber out of his grasp.*
>
> *Ren extended a hand, calling on the Force to ward off her attacks. At
> first it worked, as she slashed into the iron shield of his will, but
> then her blade cut across his face. It burned.*
>
> *He looked up at the girl whose lightsaber hovered over his chest. He
> shivered under the coldness of her stare. He who had been so eager to
> kill was not eager to die. Kylo Ren was afraid.*
>
> *The girl withdrew from him.*
>
> [Star Wars: The Force Awakens - Junior Novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Force_Awakens_(junior_novelization))

Nor the [script](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-The-Force-Awakens.html)

> Rey closes her eyes for a long beat. When Rey opens them, she is
> centered, fortified, and she POUNDS BACK, SINGLE HANDED SWIPES,
> hitting Ren's gnarly, spitting saber with incredible FORCE. It's so
> fast now, so furious, that Kylo Ren FALLS BACK -- She ATTACKS HARDER!
>
> Ren gets up again but she HITS HIS SABER'S HILT -- HIS BLADE GOES
> FLYING OFF, TUMBLING INTO THE SNOW -- and she SLASHES AGAIN AND AGAIN
> AND HITS KYLO REN SQUARE IN THE HEAD AND CHEST. HE GOES DOWN, SUDDENLY
> A FEARFUL MAN, A LARGE BURN SCAR SLASHED ACROSS HIS FACE! He still
> reaches for his saber. And she could kill him -- right now, with ONE
> VICIOUS STRIKE!
>
> **But she stops.**

Also, y'know, counting skills

[image]

Comment: @tgnat - Hand-drawn hand circles

Comment: @Richard : Did you use both hands, one for each?

Comment: @praxis - No, for precision work like that, I use a stylus clenched in my teeth.

Comment: @Richard : A true professional!  :-)